# How do the range modifiers work in ranged combat?

Tags: ranged-attack, twerps

The rules:

> Sample Missile Weapons:
>
> | Weapon | Plus to Hit | Damage | Range |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | Rock | -1 | 1 | 3 Hex |
> | Dagger | 0 | 2 | 4 Hex |
> | … |  |  |  |
> | Rifle | 1 | 3 | 10 Hex |
>
> No  missile  weapon  may  be  fired  at  an  opponent  in the  attacker's  own  hex.  There  is  a  Range  Modifier  to missile  attacks:  range  in  hexes/3  (round  down)  is  sub-tracted  from  the  roll  to  hit.

Example

Alice and Bob are 4 hexes apart from each other. Alice and Bob are 5 hexes away from  Charlie. Alice has a rifle (+1 to hit), Bob has a throwing dagger (+0 to hit), and poor Charlie has a rock (-1 to hit).

How does the Range modifier work? Aside from the weapon to hit modifier what are the range to hit modifiers for each? Can Charlie or Bob even hit anyone?

Answer (score 2):

### Subtract the distance to the target/3 as penalty to the roll

The rules text is minimal for "[the worlds easiest role playing game](https://writeups.letsyouandhimfight.com/gradenko2000/twerps-the-worlds-easiest-roleplaying-system/)", so there is nothing else to go by.

Typically, it is [harder to hit someone who is further away](https://deltasdnd.blogspot.com/2011/03/basic-d-on-archery.html), and each ranged weapon has a maximum range of how far it at best can go, beyond which you cannot reach a target or there is not enough energy left to cause meaningful damage.

I think it is likely that the language of dividing range/3 and subtracting it aims to simulate this, i.e. that "range" in the sentence "*There is a Range Modifier to missle attacks: range in hexes/3 (round down) is subtracted from the roll to hit.*" refers to the **distance to the creature** you are trying to hit, not the range property of the weapon.

Because if it was the weapon property, it would always be a fixed number, as the weapon's range never changes, and it would have been much easier to just include this in the attack modifier and not even talk about it. For example, if this referred to the range of the rifle, that range/3 is always 3, and together with the +1 to hit you would always attack with a -2 overall penalty with the rifle, no matter how far your target is away from you. That makes little sense, beacuse a rifle is obviously a better weapon than a rock for ranged combat, which would always subtract 3/3 rounded down = -1 for the same total of -2.

With this reading, the range penalty is entirely independent of the weapon, and just depends on the distance to the target to hit. How good the weapon is at hitting inherently is captured in its "to hit" property. The range penalty does not matter if the target is out of the range of the weapon, because then you cannot attack with the weapon.

So, for example, if you shoot a rifle at someone 1 or 2 hexes away, you have no penalty from distance, and with the +1 to attack from the rifle, an overall +1 on your roll. If you shoot it at someone at 3, 4 or 5 hexes away, you have a -1 penalty for a +0 on the roll, if you shoot at someone 6, 7, or 8 hexes away, you have a -2 penalty for a -1 on the roll, and at 9 or 10 hexes away, you have a -3 penalty for a -2 on the roll. You cannot shoot someone 11 or more hexes away.

A dagger could be thrown 4 hexes. It has 0 to hit modifier by itself and would have no penalty for distance if thrown 1 or 2 hexes, and a -1 modifier for distance if thrown at a target 3 or 4 hexes away. You cannot throw it more than 4 hexes.

| Attacker | Weapon | Base Mod | Range | Target | Distance | Distance mod | Roll mod |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Alice | Rifle | +1 | 10 | Bob | 4 | -1 | **0** |
| Alice | Rifle | +1 | 10 | Charlie | 5 | -1 | **0** |
| Bob | Dagger | +0 | 4 | Alice | 4 | -1 | **-1** |
| Bob | Dagger | +0 | 4 | Charlie | 5 | -1 | out of range |
| Charlie | Rock | -1 | 3 | Alice | 5 | -1 | out of range |
| Charlie | Rock | -1 | 3 | Bob | 5 | -1 | out of range |